# Save encrypted data in django field

Tags: django, encryption, django-models

I want to save my email as a encrypted value and in future other fields aswell may include. I am trying this pip packedge [django-encrypted-model-fields](https://pypi.org/project/django-encrypted-model-fields/)

Now its working fine . I included in installed apps and Created a Field like

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    encrypted_char_field = EncryptedCharField(max_length=100)
```

but when I store data in it like

```
    user = self.model(encrypted_char_field='hello')
    user.save()
```

its saving normal data,not encrypted data.how I can save encrypted data in it ?

Comment: @ArtjomB.  I have updated question kindly check

Comment: How do you know that it is not encrypted? How do you validate it?